# Why do NBA players avoid touching the ball after a made basket?

Tags: rules, basketball, nba

I notice this a lot in the NBA, where after a team scores a field goal, the players of that team that are positioned near or directly under the basket for an offensive rebound avoid touching the ball. They often avoid even making contact with the ball as they try to make their way back to halfcourt for the next possession.

Is there a rule violation about touching the ball after your team makes a field goal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is such a rule, and the players want to avoid any possible hint of breaching it.

> Section II. Delay of Game
>
> a. A delay-of-game  shall  be  called  for:
>
> (1) Preventing  the  ball  from  being  promptly  put  into  play.
>
> (2) Interfering  with  the  ball  after  a  successful  field  goal  or  free  throw.
>
> ...

Comment: I'd also add that initially, the player receives a warning for delay of game before a technical foul is given if it happens again.

Comment: @Andrei - team receives warning not player.

Answer (score 1):

Delay of game is called when an offensive player intentionally touches the ball after it has been scored.

This rule was implemented because when the offense touches the ball, it's very easy for them to direct it away from the referee or from the opposing team. This can prevent the opposing team from inbounding the ball for a fraction of a second or more. And even the smallest time delay can prevent the opposing team from leading to a transition offense.

Because teams began touching the ball to prevent fast breaks, while forcing more half court sets, it became the standard that they cannot touch the ball after it has been scored.